# Is there a term for the process of "taking a logarithm"?

Tags: logarithms, terminology, exponentiation

I recently learned that there is a term for taking a function and raising a constant (almost exclusively $e$ in the scope of my studies) to the power of that function.

i.e., $\ln x = -kt$ can be written $x = e^{-kt}$ and the process of raising $e$ to the power of $-kt$ is called exponentiation.

I was wondering if there was a similar term that was a descriptive alternative to saying "taking the logarithm."

i.e., $x = e^{-kt}$ can be written as $\ln x = \ln e^{-kt} = -kt$, and I was wondering if there was a one-word name that replaced "taking the logarithm."

Comment: it is called "logarithming"

Comment: @Peter Now that was funny!

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, funny, but as far as I know it is the terminology.

Comment: @Peter I've never seen or heard the term until 1 minute ago.

Comment: In Russian it is called logarithming, or close enough

Comment: This is the first time I also have seen "logarithming" in a serious context.

Comment: "...taking the logarithm."  Similarly you would never talk about "sining" an angle when you compute $\sin (\theta)$ but instead "...taking the sine of the angle theta."  Or "tangetting" or....

Comment: I've only ever heard "taking the logarithm", or "taking logarithms" or "logs". The suggestion "logarithming" is funny, but I'm pretty sure it's not generally used.

Comment: Even if I am wrong, and it is not the common word, I think it actually makes sense. "sining an equation" - this would be very funny indeed.

Comment: I say "log" or "logging," as in "log both sides of the equation," etc.

Comment: log in and log off. So "log in= logarism" and "log out=expotism".

Comment: What about "squaring" ? This is common rather than "taking the square", isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Logarithming" sounds like some sort of bad competition where you carve wooden logs or something, but everyone somewhat mathematically inclined would most likely understand that you mean "taking the logarithm" with this.

On that note; what I always use myself is what you said yourself, namely "taking the logarithm" or "taking the log of". For me personally I don't see this as a problem, but if you actually do want to call it something else I guess you could call it "inverse exponentiation" or something like that, which is correct but not really easier to say than "taking the log of". Or you can start using "logarithming" which will probably raise some eyebrows at first.

Comment: The term логарифмирование which is the same as logarithming was widely used in Russian works and it's possible that it exists in some of the English translations at least